# Excel formula to Google sheets formula

Tags: excel

I have this formula for an Excel worksheet I use to track appointments. It works great but now I need to share it real-time with other members of my organization so I uploaded the workbook to Google sheets but of course, the formula doesn't translate (work).

How can I adjust the formula below to work in Google sheets?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim AddRange As Range
    Set AddRange = Range("C4:C100")  '' Your add appointment range

    If Not Intersect(Target, AddRange) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value <> "Add Appointment" Then
            Exit Sub
        Else
            Range("B" & Target.Row).Value = Range("B" & Target.Row).Value + 1
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi it would be more clear if you added a sheet with data and what you exactly want, but with my basic understanding of question this should help i think.

```
function ifFunction() {
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  // Put your range below between ("") of input 
  var workingRange = spreadSheet.getRange("");

  // if(workingRange = here should be your criteria)
  if (workingRange = ) {
    spreadSheet.getRange("C1:C100").setValue("Add Appointment");
  } else { 
  // Put your formula below in .setValue
    spreadSheet.getRange("C1:C100").setValue("");
  }
}
```

Make necessary changes below the comments.

Comment: Good day Shiva, thank you for your prompt response! I copied and pasted into the sheet I have in my Google drive but got this error below. It's probably something I'm doing incorrectly- Syntax Error: Unexpected token ) (line 7, file "Code.gs"). I will attach a sample of the Excel sheet I would like to convert.

Comment: How do I attach the Excel sample sheet?

Comment: @Ediddy since you want script in googlesheet edit the question and you have option to insert links you can add your sheet in there make sure you give access to public

Comment: Here is the link- https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Btt6nqGIcQyulKm6LoiwfMKkktVW4O0bSmWSRy4rwE4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Ediddy it will be great if you explain here or put the `=if function` in provided sheet so that i would understand what is the desired output